# How can I release a method before execution the method using java

Tags: java, web

This is method that I call from view page:

```
public void methodA() {
    methodB();
    System.out.println("Complete");
}

public void methodB() {
    // some operation go here
    //it's execution time is minimum 5 min
}
```

My Question is : I want to release from `methodB()` before completing execution `methodB()` and I want to print "Complete" which is included in `methodA();`

Comment: Read about *multithreading* in Java.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088603/how-to-make-calling-a-method-as-a-background-process-in-java) will help you go about to achieve what you need.

Comment: Is this in Swing? There are background task classes to do exactly that pretty conveniently. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want some kind of asynchronous processing. You want to call `methodB()` asynchronously and exit `methodA` before `methodB` is completed.

There a lot of ways to achieve this but the simplest and not the best way to do this is using threads:

```
public void methodA() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            methodB();
        }
    }.start();
    System.out.println("methodB is called asynchronously");
}
```

You can improve this using thread pulls, executors framework, queues etc. Choosing of concrete solution depends on your needs. You are welcome to learn how to work with threads in java and then ask more concrete question. I hope however that this answer can give you the "right" direction.