# Java scheduled task to keep running in an interval repeatedly, in background

Tags: java, multithreading

I want my main program to keep executing while `updateRecord` method runs in the background. The `updateRecord` method keeps updating the expiry time of a record in an interval.

Here is my `updateRecord` method.

```
    public void updateRecord(LeaderRecord leader) {
      LeaderRecord record = data.get(leader.getType());
      synchronized (this) {
        if (leader.getId().equals(record.getId()) || leader.getVersion() == record.getVersion()) {
          Runnable runnable = () -> {
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, timeLimit);
            leader.setExpiryTime(new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime()));
            data.put(leader.getType(), leader);
            System.out.println(record.getExpiryTime());
          };
          ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
          service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, timeLimit, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
      }
    }
```

This code stops running after printing the time once.
What should I do to make it keep running in the background while the main application executes?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make calling a Method as a background process in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088603/how-to-make-calling-a-method-as-a-background-process-in-java)

Comment: you can use TimerTask, there you have scheduleAtFixedRate method, where you can specify your task and periodic timings to execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a Timer. They should be what you are looking for. It is similar to what you are doing, but it has all of the functionality you are looking for built into it.

```
public static void updateRecord(LeaderRecord leader) {
    long timeLimit = 5000;//ms
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, timeLimit);
            leader.setExpiryTime(new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime()));
            data.put(leader.getType(), leader);
            System.out.println(record.getExpiryTime());
        }
    }, 0, timeLimit);// Delay, Time Between in ms
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it stops after executing once. I want it to keep running repeatedly.

Comment: This is the way to go. the reason your method and this method are not working now, is that their is an exception not being caught somewhere. for starters, remove everything inside the run() override, and simply have it console out a string like "RUN". This should get the intervals going

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.Timer` to run a task at a set interval.

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() { //(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateRecord(leader);
    }
}, 0, 3600000); //delay = 0, interval in milliseconds
```

This will keep the program running forever until you stop it. Use

```
t.cancel();
t.purge();
```

to stop the `Timer` or

```
System.exit(0);
```

to terminate the application.